# What array should I choose to insert this json object in it?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am having a hard time with these arrays in Android. I am a newbie to Android. I know it is a simple question but even when googling it I couldn't find something that would help(I know there are many sites but I am not really sure what I need in this case).

I have a JSON object which contains some arrays and I would like to push them to an Array which will be called later at another class. Take a look below and see if this is totally wrong or right:

```
//this is inited right after creating a class
public static ArrayList[] jsonResponse = new ArrayList[]{};

//inside a method
strResp = response.body().string();
jsonResponse.add(strResp);
```

**other class:**

```
//right after creating the class
private FirstClass firstClass;

public void getdata() {
   System.out.println("Array : " + firstClass.jsonResponse);
}
```

Comment: can you provide json data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usualy do this:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public static JSONArray jsonResponses = new JSONArray(); 

//inside a method
    strResp = response.body().string();
    try {
        jsonResponses.put(new JSONObject(strResp));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Other class:

```
private FirstClass firstClass;

public void getdata() {
   System.out.println("Array : " + firstClass.jsonResponses);
}
```

If you dont want to push data, but only replace previews:

```
try {
        jsonResponses = new JSONArray(response.body().string());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: this creates pushes the data without cleaning arrayfirst so it overloads

Comment: @bmm I concluded that you want that behaivor according to your code but ok. It's even simpler, I am edditing previews answer...